# jQuery: add class to body if keyword is in URL

Tags: jquery

I have URLs that are like that: 
https://example.com/page1/#keyword1
https://example.com/page1/#keyword2
I am looking for a piece of jQuery code that adds a certain class to the body, if a certain keyword is part of the URL.

Has anybody ideas? I know it is possible, but I could not find any suggestions that worked.

e.g.https://example.com/#keyword1 should create HTML like this:

```
<body class="keyword1">
bla bla bla
</body>
```

Thank you for hints!

Comment: The keywords are in `window.location.hash`. What more do you need to know for this?

Comment: var hash = window.location.hash; $('body').addClass(hash.replace('#','');

Comment: Do you always want to add the hash as the class, or only match certain hashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this on page load using `window.location.hash`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var hash = window.location.hash;
   if (hash) {
      hash = hash.replace('#', '');
      $("body").addClass(hash);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the full URL using `window.location.href` then split it to array using any character by [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) then add this string as a class to your body

**Example**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href
    $("body").addClass(url.split("#")[1])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the certain keyword with the help of "window.location.href.indexOf("lorem")>0", this will return true in case the word exists and then you can add the class to body e.g. $("body").addClass("ipsum").

Note: "lorem"- keyword/substring to be found in url
      "ipsum"- the class to be added in body